# How to sort text file based on number after first letter

Tags: linux, sorting, grep

I have a text file in linux that looks like this:

```
H-988   -0.5418829321861267 no
H-989   -0.5033702254295349 yes
H-990   -1.1516857147216797 hi
H-99    -0.5005123019218445 hello
```

I want to sort this file based on the number coming after the hyphen. So the order should be:

```
H-99    -0.5005123019218445 hello
H-988   -0.5418829321861267 no
H-989   -0.5033702254295349 yes
H-990   -1.1516857147216797 hi
```

I tried the grep `sort` command but it did not work. For example it puts 95 after 949 instead of before same goes for 99 and 990 as the example provided

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should sort as numerically,

```
sort --numeric-sort --field-separator "-" --key 2 some.txt
```

or a shorter version

```
sort -n -t "-" -k 2 some.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first field always has only two characters before the number, you can skip them:

```sh
sort -k1.3,1n ip.txt
```

`-k1.3` tells `sort` to start considering the field (which is `1` here) only from the third character